# Multiple Domain redirect on a Single Hosting.

Tags: php, redirect

I've website `mainsite.com` and `subsite.com` which redirect to sub folder `/subsite/` on main site

-If people browse to mainsite it will redirect to myofficialsite.com with a php script
-If browse to elsewhere will go there `eg: mainsite.com/xxx/yyy/`

I have a folder call /subsite/ which hold all my subsite
It is fine when browse to mainsite.com/subsite/somefile.html
It is fine when browse to subsite.com/

I got problem 404 when browse to www.subsite.com/somefile.html

My redirect script is like this

```
    <?php
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$page=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$domain=strtolower($domain);
if ($domain == "subsite.com"||$domain == "www.subsite.com") {header( "Location: http://www.mainsite.com/subsite/$page" );}
else { header( "Location: http://www.myofficialsite.com/" ); }

?>
```

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Sorry I did not tell you previously. Server is IIS, I think it is not support .htaccess.

Comment: http://www.helicontech.com/ape/ check it, maybe it will help you.